# Toggle button with panel in Firefox extension with Mozilla SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a firefox extension with the Mozilla SDK. The situation is:
I want a toggle/action button to show/hide the extension's panel.

My code:

```
// the panel
let panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    // ...
    onHide: handleHide
});

// the button
let button = ToggleButton({
    // ...
    // will be executed, when user clicks the button
    onChange: handleChange
});

// event handlers
function handleChange(state) {
    // state.checked is always true
    if (???) {
        panel.show();
    } 
}

function handleHide() {
    // un-check the button
    button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

The problem is, that inside of *handleChange*, where the toggling logic should be, i can't tell if the panel is supposed to show or hide. [In the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Panel_Positioning) theres an example which uses *state.checked*, but since this code is run while i am clicking on the button, the *state.checked* is always true. In the end, the toggling does not work this way, because the panel never gets hidden when clicking the "toggle"-button.

help much appreaciated, i already tried so many things.. mothings works. 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Firefox 30? It could be that this code doesn't work as expected in Firefox < 30 – most of the focus and panel integration for panels and toggle buttons are landed in Firefox 30.

Answer (score 2):

simply use console.log to see what's inside the **state**:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "checked": false,
  "label": "the default label",
  "icon": "./icon.png",
  "id": "show-panel"
}
```

so we can go on like this:

```
if(state.checked)
{
   myExt.show();
   return false;
} else {
   myExt.hide();
   return false;
}
```

in older versions you need to **return false**.